# VBA Delete columns in all sheets where sheetname contains text

Tags: excel, vba, contains, worksheet

My coding experience is very limited and i'm struggling a bit to understand why my code is not working. I am just going off different forums and help sites to stitch together my code, and i've got parts of it down. The code i've got makes a copy of all Sheets in the workbook, and names it the original name + "_Deal" with this code:

```
For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    xWs.Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
    ActiveSheet.Name = xWs.Name & "_Deal"
Next
```

Then i've tried to add this code to delete column 7 (G) from all of the sheets containing "_Deal":

```
For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
If InStr(ActiveSheet.Name, "_Deal") <> 0 Then Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete
Next
```

Also tried replacing "ActiveSheet.Name" with "xWs.Name". The result seems to be that it does delete column 7 in **one** sheet containing "_Deal", but not all. And i kinda don't understand why the "For Each xWs in ThisWorkbook.Sheets" does work on the first code to actually copy all sheets, while in the second it stops after having executed the code in one sheet..

I'm going a bit step by step, but my end goal is to 1) Make a copy of all sheets named "... _Deal", 2) Delete columns 7-10 (G-J) in the copies (but i figured i should just start with one, then figure out how to delete all four columns later), 3) Save all sheets to a new workbook (got that code down), and finally 4) delete the copy sheets containing "_Deal" (not yet attempted that part, but hoping i can use the same as for columns but just switch the delete columns-part with a delete sheet command).

Any help or input will be appreciated :)

Comment: `If InStr(xWs.Name, "_Deal") <> 0 Then xWs.Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete` - you must always specify the sheet, otherwise the active sheet is assumed and that does not change. Btw you don't need two loops.

Comment: Ooooh, thanks, that does make sense! It works now! :D doesn't seem to work when i try to merge it into the same loop tho... Not entirely sure why. I guess it would be more efficient to have it in one, but not really a problem for me to keep it in 2 loops. It works, so it works! Thanks! :D

Comment: Update: I changed xWs to ActiveSheets both in the InStr and before the columns.delete, and it seems to be working while keeping it within the same loop now!